# Simplify update-statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have the fallowing update-statement:

```
update tmp set 
tmp.Anzahl=(select sum(a.BNANZ) from PAYMASTER_Journal a where a.BNARTID=tmp.ArtikelAutoID), 
tmp.Betrag=(select sum(a.BNBETR) from PAYMASTER_Journal a where a.BNARTID=tmp.ArtikelAutoID), 
tmp.Rabatt=(select sum(a.BNRMRBETR) from PAYMASTER_Journal a where a.BNARTID=tmp.ArtikelAutoID) 
from ##tmp1 tmp
```

On this way, for each record in ##tmp1, there are 3 subqueries executed. ##tmp1 contains 10'000 records -> totaly 30'000 subqueries.

Because each subquery selects the same records from PAYMASTER_Journal, I am searching for a way, to update ##tmp1 with executing only one subquery per record in ##tmp1.

I hope, someone can help me about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `LEFT JOIN` try this

```
update tmp set 
tmp.Anzahl=BNANZ_accumulated, 
tmp.Betrag=BNBETR_accumulated, 
tmp.Rabatt=BNRMRBETR_accumulated
from ##tmp1 tmp 
LEFT JOIN  ( SELECT BNARTID, 
                SUM(BNANZ) AS BNANZ_accumulated, 
                SUM(BNBETR) AS BNBETR_accumulated,
                SUM(BNRMRBETR) AS BNRMRBETR_accumulated 
                FROM PAYMASTER_Journal 
                WHERE (ARTIKELAUSWAHL=0x30 AND BLBONSTO=0x30 AND BLZESTO=0x30 AND 
                      STORNO=0x30 AND 
                      BDDAT BETWEEN '20120301' AND '20130821' AND 
                      AdressID='d68e4d8f-e60e-4482-9730-76076948df43' AND
                      BNFIL=5 AND 
                      ISNULL(Preisliste, 'VK-Preisliste') =  'VK-Preisliste' AND 
                      BNARTID=tmp.ArtikelAutoID) 

                GROUP BY BNARTID) a ON a.BNARTID=tmp.ArtikelAutoID
```

this will leave you `NULL` when there is no rows in `PAYMASTER_Journal` for a given ##tmp1.ArtikelAutoID

if you don't want to touch them, change the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`

Comment: One more question: The effective where of the subselect is much complexer that this on in my sample. It is: (ARTIKELAUSWAHL=0x30 AND BLBONSTO=0x30 AND BLZESTO=0x30 AND STORNO=0x30 AND BDDAT>='20120301' AND BDDAT<='20130821' AND AdressID='d68e4d8f-e60e-4482-9730-76076948df43' AND BNFIL=5) AND (Preisliste='VK-Preisliste' OR Preisliste IS NULL) AND  BNARTID=tmp.ArtikelAutoID) 
What does I have to do with the group in your solution this case?

Comment: @ThomasKehl something like the edited response? **I'm that the `where` clause is for table `PAYMASTER_Journal`**

Comment: yes. And no, i think i see: the group by is needed because of the corelation between ##tmp1 and PAYMASTER_Journal?

Comment: The group is for getting the relation between both tables, what do you mean by Yes and no... shall I compute as IF (1 = 0)?

Comment: I mean yes for "I'm what the where ..." - and the other sould not be "And no, ..." - instead: "And now, ..."

Comment: So, does my response satisfies you?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with `MERGE` statement:

```
merge ##tmp1
using   (select 
            BNARTID
            ,sum(BNANZ) as BNANZ
            ,sum(BNBETR) as BNBETR
            ,sum(BNRMRBETR) as BNRMRBETR
        from 
            PAYMASTER_Journal
        group by
            BNARTID
        ) as upd
on tmp.ArtikelAutoID = upd.BNARTID
when matched then update set Anzahl=BNANZ, Betrag=BNBETR, Rabatt=BNRMRBETR;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single sub-query as follows.

```
UPDATE  tmp T 
INNER JOIN
        (SELECT a.BNARTID
                ,sum(a.BNANZ) as BANAZ_SUM
                ,sum(a.BNBETR) as BNBETR_SUM
                ,sum(a.BNRMRBETR) as BNRMRBETR_SUM
        FROM    PAYMASTER_Journal a
        WHERE   a.BNARTID = tmp.ArtikelAutoID
        GROUP BY
                a.BNARTID
        ) SQ
ON      SQ.BNARTID = tmp.ArtikelAutoID       
SET     tmp.Anzahl = SQ.BANAZ_SUM
        ,tmp.Betrag = SQ.BNBETR_SUM
        ,tmp.Rabatt = SQ.BNRMRBETR_SUM
```